# Creating objects in Hy

Tags: python, qt, lisp, pyside, hy

I've looked all over the documentation of Hy, but I can't find a way to create objects anywhere. More specifically, I'm trying to follow [this PySide tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Hello-World-in-PySide), but converting each command to Hy, and I'm not sure how to do `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` in Hy. Would appreciate all the help possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python you create an object by calling the constructor, a function that has the same name as the class. The exact same applies in Hy.

```
(import sys)
(import [PySide.QtGui [QApplication]])

(setf app (QApplication sys.argv))
```

Notes:

- You assign the object created with `setf`
- Be sure to import all the necessary modules

Comment: When I try to do that, I get the following error message: ``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QApplication' is not defined``

Comment: It looks like you're missing the proper imports. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks - that did it. Now however, I'm not sure how to call the ``app.exec()`` function - I tried ``(.exec app)`` and ``(exec app)``, but neither worked.

Comment: Read the doc. The function is `exec_`. Try `(.exec_ app)`. (PS you should include an error message instead of saying "neither worked").

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried ``(.exec_ app)``, but then my Hy REPL gave me the following message and exited: ``ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 28654, errno = 32``

Comment: This is an issue with PySide and has nothing to do with Hy. It's way beyond the original scope of your question which was about object creation in Hy. I cannot help you here.